# CASE Statement causing execute time to sky rocket

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, common-table-expression

There are two distinct databases where I work. In creating a report (utilizing TSQL) to share between departments, it was requested to have a field to show the information from the primary database (information kept on the college's database) had also been inputted into a second database (that a specific department uses for information communications with federal program).  Without checking the second database with the case statement the query for the rest of the information takes less than a second.  With the case statement (in which CTEs where created to conduct the check), it has run for 15 minutes and not finished before I manually ended the execution. Here is the code (CASE statement currently commented out):

```
With POWERFAIDS_CHECK as
        (
        Select distinct NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM, 
                (CAST (NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM as VARCHAR) + CAST (EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT as VARCHAR) ) as CHECK_ID
        
            From NAME_MASTER
            JOIN EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS on NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM = EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.ID_NUM
            JOIN SCHOLARSHIP on EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT = SCHOLARSHIP.AID_ELEMENT
            JOIN PF_FUND_CDE_MSTR on EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT = PF_FUND_CDE_MSTR.RPT_CATEGORY
            JOIN PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.student on NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM = PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.student.alternate_id
            JOIN PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.funds on  PF_FUND_CDE_MSTR.FUND_CDE = PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.funds.fund_ledger_number
            JOIN PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award_year on PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.student.student_token = PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award_year.student_token
            JOIN PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award on PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award_year.stu_award_year_token = PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award.stu_award_year_token
            JOIN YEAR_TERM_TABLE on (YEAR_TERM_TABLE.YR_CDE = EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.YR_CDE) and (YEAR_TERM_TABLE.TRM_CDE = EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.TRM_CDE)

            Where EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.YR_CDE = '2021'
            and EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.TRM_CDE = 'FA'
            and YEAR_TERM_TABLE.TRM_BEGIN_DTE = PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award.award_period_begin_dt
            and EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AWARD_AMT = PowerFAIDS_Production.dbo.stu_award.actual_amt
            and stu_award.status = 'A'
        ),

    AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS as

        (Select distinct NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM, (NAME_MASTER.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + NAME_MASTER.LAST_NAME) as STUDENT_NAME, 
                SCHOLARSHIP.DESCRIPTION,
                Format (EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AWARD_AMT, 'C','en-us') as AWARD_AMT, 
                EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.COMMENTS,
                YR_DESC, TRM_DESC, EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT,
                (CAST (NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM as VARCHAR) + CAST (EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT as VARCHAR) ) as CHECK_ID,
                NAME_MASTER.LAST_NAME, NAME_MASTER.FIRST_NAME
        
        From NAME_MASTER
            JOIN EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS on NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM = EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.ID_NUM
            JOIN SCHOLARSHIP on EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT = SCHOLARSHIP.AID_ELEMENT
            JOIN YEAR_DEF on EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.YR_CDE = YEAR_DEF.YR_CDE
            JOIN TERM_DEF on EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.TRM_CDE = TERM_DEF.TRM_CDE
            Where EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.TRM_CDE = 'FA'
            and EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.YR_CDE = '2021'
            and EX_SCHOLARSHIP_RECIPIENTS.AID_ELEMENT not between '5000' and '5999'
    )

    Select distinct AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.ID_NUM, STUDENT_NAME,
            AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.DESCRIPTION, AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.AWARD_AMT, 
            
                --CASE
                --  WHEN AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.CHECK_ID not in (Select CHECK_ID from POWERFAIDS_CHECK)
                --  THEN 'No'
                --  ELSE 'Yes'
                --END as Processed_FA_Award,
                
                AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.COMMENTS,
            AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.YR_DESC, AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.TRM_DESC, AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.LAST_NAME, AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.FIRST_NAME
    From AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN POWERFAIDS_CHECK on AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.ID_NUM = POWERFAIDS_CHECK.ID_NUM
    Where AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.ID_NUM in (Select ID_NUM from AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS)

    Order by AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.DESCRIPTION, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
```

Any insights much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Also get in the habit of giving your objects aliases, it'll make your queries *far* more succinct and therefore readable.

Comment: Do you *need* all those `DISTINCT`s? The operator is very expensive, and normally if you need it in a query like the above it's an indicator that your `JOIN`s may not wrong.

Comment: Something seems terribly wrong when you left join to `POWERFAIDS_CHECK` while also using that table in your subquery. It is odd that you use different columns for what seems like the same "join". Schema issues will often lead to poorly performing queries.

Comment: And if your computation for CHECK_ID involves numeric numbers, your code can produce misleading information. Converting the tuples <11, 2> and <1, 12> both result in '112'.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a definitive answer here without knowing what your data and indexes look like. If you can share your the execution plan for both versions of your query it would be way easier to give you a clear answer.

You can share you execution plans here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Without the execution plan here are a couple of ideas to try:

1. `EXISTS` often performs better than `IN/NOT IN`

`CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM POWERFAIDS_CHECK WHERE CHECK_ID = AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.CHECK_ID) THEN [...]`

2. Adding a new CTE that contains the subset of data you need might help:

`), VALID_CHECK_IDS AS ( SELECT DISTINCT CHECK_ID FROM POWER_FAIDS_CHECK )`

Then use this CTE in your case statement.

3. Add a second join to POWERFAIDS_CHECK

`LEFT JOIN POWERFAIDS_CHECK AS VALIDCHECKID ON AWARDED_SCHOLARSHIPS.CHECK_ID = POWERFAIDS_CHECK.CHECK_ID`

and update your case to

`CASE WHEN VALIDCHECKID.CHECK_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' [...]`